# CL_INVALID_BUILD_OPTIONS on MacOSX

Tags: c++, opencl

I have written an OpenCL program on MacOSX. The program defines the following build options:

```
-D T=ushort  -D MAX_VAL=65535 -D MIN_VAL=-65535
```

The kernel can be executed for all the built-in C++ types. for example, if T=uchar, then the program will define the next options:

```
-D T=uchar  -D MAX_VAL=255 -D MIN_VAL=-255
```

But when I run the program it crashes with error `CL_INVALID_BUILD_OPTIONS`

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: It (the program) *crashes*? Or it *fails to compile* ? emitting an invalid build flags error message would be an awfully odd thing for *your* program to do.

Comment: solved, Mac dislike double whitespaces between program options

Comment: That seemed to be the direction this would go. A quick look at the help text for clang reveals `-Dmacro[=defn]` as the proper declaration method for macros. You should write an answer for your question (which is allowed on SO, and in-fact, encouraged if your solve your own problem). I'll up-vote it as it is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned in the comments, the whitespace is the issue. This should work if you changed your options to:

```
-DT=ushort -DMAX_VAL=65535 -DMIN_VAL=-65535
```

I was going to suggest that you made use of the constants defined in `limits.h`, although having looked through the [OpenCL Specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf#page=234), it says that the header cannot be included.